# If/ifelse and setting variables in Twig in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, twig, conditional-statements

I'm new to Twig and am having a problem with displaying a date in the AP format. I am setting a variable for the date month and I have an if statement to set the month number to month name abbreviation of that month. However, it is not working. I believe my syntax is wrong based on the fact that this is a long conditional. ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
{% set show_month = show.get_field('start_date') | date('n') - 1 %}
{% set show_month_numerical = show.get_field('start_date') | date('m') %}
 {% if show_month_numerical == '01' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Jan.' %}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '02' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Feb.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '08' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Aug.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '09' %}
  {%s set how_month_apstyle = 'Sept.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '10' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Oct.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '11' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Nov.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '12' %}
  {%  set show_month_apstyle = 'Dec.'%}
 {% endif %}
  
  <h2 class="beta">           
  <span class="start-date-mdy">{{ show.get_field('start_date')|date('m j, Y') }}</span>
  </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
{% set show_month = show.get_field('start_date') | date('n') - 1 %}
{% set show_month_numerical = show.get_field('start_date') | date('m') %}
 {% if show_month_numerical == '01' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Jan.' %}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '02' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Feb.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '08' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Aug.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '09' %}
  {%s set how_month_apstyle = 'Sept.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '10' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Oct.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '11' %}
  {% set show_month_apstyle = 'Nov.'%}
 {% elseif show_month_numerical == '12' %}
  {%  set show_month_apstyle = 'Dec.'%}
 {% endif %}
  
  <h2 class="beta">           
  <span class="start-date-mdy">{{ show_month_apstyle }}{{ show.get_field('start_date')|date('j, Y') }}</span>
   </h2>
```